# How to send data to Server

Tags: android, server

I want to make a login. So how I send the username and the password to my server? I wrote a php script for the server. He will receive the username and the password and if the username and password are correct he will respond 'succes'. So how to send to the Server? And after sending with onResponse?

Comment: You need to make `Webservice` to interact with server. For that you have to learn Server scripting language like `PHP` along with `MySql`. For the reference you can see this nice example - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: @Wizard please read question carefully he want how to send from device data to server?,  you can learn from here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: @Wizard thank you bhura!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OkHttp  to achieve this easily. In order to include the library use the following in dependencies:
**compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'**

As a sample you can use it like this:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("username", USER_NAME)
                .add("password", PASSWORD)
                .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if(response.code == 200){
String responseData = responses.body().string(); 
  //Process the response Data
  }else{
     //Server problem
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate Android mobile client with the server. This tutorial is a brief guide on how to integrate your Android App to WAMP Server. This server could be hosted on you local machine or on a remote server.

[Connecting your Android app to your WAMP server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800703/Connecting-your-Android-app-to-your-WAMP-server)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use any networking library like volley,Retrofit or you can also use Httpurlconnection to send data to server.Here is an example of sending data to server using httpurlconnection.
https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Follow these links for this

[1]:------ http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

[2]:------ http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/