# How to get data from text view in first activity and post it from another activity?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, android-intent

I want the data of textview in the second activity to pass in the third but i dont want to display it in the third activity. I want to directly send the data from the second activity to Pass in my sql db after clicking the button in the final activity. Is is achievable? 
This is my first activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText email, password;
private Button btn_login;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_LOGIN ="http://192.168.1.83/Attendance/login.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loading= findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.editTextUserEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);


    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPassword.isEmpty()) {
                Login(mEmail, mPassword);
            }else{
                email.setError("Please Enter Email");
                password.setError("Please Enter Password");

            }


        }
    });

}

private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.d("JSON", jsonObject.toString());
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = 
jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                        if (success.equals("1"))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject object = 
jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = 
object.getString("name").trim();
                                String email = 
object.getString("email").trim();

//                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
"Success Login \nYour name: "+name+"\nYour Email: "+email,
 //                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new 
  Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                startActivity(intent);
                              loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" 
 +e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" 
+error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

This is my second activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView name,email;
private TextView welcome;
private Button Send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    Send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcome);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    String extraName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String extraEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email");


    name.setText(extraName);
    email.setText(extraEmail);

    Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,StatusActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("wel", welcome.getText().toString());
            intent1.putExtra("name1", name.getText().toString());
            intent1.putExtra("email1", email.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent1);


        }
    });
}
```

And this is my final activity but Here i dont want to show the text view i just want to post it from here.

```
public class StatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView welcome, name, email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
    welcome = findViewById(R.id.abcd);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name1);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email1);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    String extraName1 = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
    String extraEmail1 = intent.getStringExtra("email1");
    String extraWelcome = intent.getStringExtra("wel");


    name.setText(extraName1);
    email.setText(extraEmail1);
    welcome.setText(extraWelcome);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty clear until you put MySql to the topic. Why you want to pass the data from one activity to another through the database. Why involve database operations which take time and resources.

You may pass data from one activity to another through `Intent`s (primitive values, `String`s and `Parcelable`s)!

All you have to do is:

1. Get the data (int your case from TextView).
2. Create the Intent to navigate to the next Activity.
3. Put the data to the Intent.
4. Start the Activity.
5. Retrieve the data from the Intent.

For example if will navigate to the next Activity via button click then in that button's `onClick()`:

```
// 1.
String data = myTextView.getText();
// 2. 
Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext,YourNextActivity.class);
// 3.
intent.putStringExtra("MY DATA KEY",data);
// 4.
yourContext.startActivity(intent);
// 5. Now in YourNextActivity's onCreate();
String retrievedData = YourNextActivity.this.getIntent().getStringExtra("MY DATA KEY");

// Done!
```

Comment: Thats not my question sir. I want the data from one activity and pass that data to my server from another activity.

Comment: So what you're telling me is this: I want the data from ActivityA and pass that data to my server from ActivityB. This sentence makes no sense (to me at least). So I am guessing that you first need to pass the data from ActivityA to ActivityB and then from ActivityB pass it to your server.

Comment: I want the data from activity A to activity b and then push it with the help of a button from activity c. But I dont want to display the data in activity c.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the value from activity a to b without displaying it in activity b? and then pass it to the server from activity b

Comment: You don't have to display it somewhere, just pass it from one activity to another as I showed above. Nobody forces you to display it. You can pass the data as I described, you can make a static reference of this data, even to store to SharedPreferences as @Tamir Abutbul described or many other options...

Comment: What is the size of that data you want to pass?

Comment: Can u please show me ..how to pass the retrieved data to the server. Sorry I am new to android development.

Comment: There are only 4 textfields .. username, id , email and the value of button

Comment: You can use OkHttp library to complete this task, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552524/9164071

Comment: I am kinda confused .. supposed I passed my value from activity a to b ..now how do I pass it to server from the second activity.

Comment: You need to pass data from an android application to a server. `Activity`s can collect data from the user (any activity, whichever you want) and then make use of the OkHttp library I showed to accomplish that task. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552524/9164071

Comment: I hope you are getting my question. Suppose I passed the data like u said ..now how do it pass it to server from the second activity

Comment: I got the data from activity a to b and got it in activity b ..now how I pass it to the server .. can u please show it using my example if u dont mind.. i will really appreciate it.

Comment: Upload your project to github and post a link here and I will check it out

Comment: I have put all the codes with my question .. I have passed the values in my second activity from the first activity and now i want to pass it to the third activity without displaying it.. because in the third activity i have a radio button from where i want to send the values from my second activity and the value of radio button to be sent to the server all together.